# How to give permissions to my uploaded aws lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-amplify

I need to give permission for all logged users on my application.

This is my code:

```js
    this.amplifyService.auth().currentUserCredentials().then(credentials => {

      const lambda = new Lambda({
        credentials: this.amplifyService.auth().essentialCredentials(credentials)
      });
      lambda.invoke({
        FunctionName: 'my-function',
      }, res => {
        console.log(res);
      });
    });
```

And this is the return:

> authRole/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: lambda:InvokeFunction on resource: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:function:my-function

I already try to create a IAM role manually:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:us-east-2:XXXXXXXXX:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:us-east-2:XXXXX:log-group:/aws/lambda/my-function:*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:XXXXXXXXX:function:my-function"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But doesn't work yet.

Comment: Are you looking in the `us-east-2` (Ohio) region in the AWS console?

Comment: Yeas, I am in the us-east-2 region in AWS console.

Comment: Are you using aws-amplify?

Comment: If you created the Lambda function using the awscli then use the awscli again to list the Lambda functions in the same region (`aws lambda list-functions --region xxx`). Does it appear in the output?

Comment: Hi @jarmod, I found the problem, the function doens't have been uploaded, but still can't access it by app.

Comment: OK, I'm still not sure what you're describing, but I'm glad you've found the problem.